# When to use .bind() in JS

Tags: javascript

There is a ton of blogs and posts about how to use `bind()` and how it's different than `call()` and `apply()`, but there is very little examples to **when** or **why** should I use `bind()`

I found many of the examples given are very uncommon occurrences such as this:

```
"use strict";

function Person(firstName, lastName){
  this.firstName = firstName
  this.lastName = lastName
}

Person.prototype.say = function(message){
  return '[' + this + ']: ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + ' said: "' + message + '"'
}

Person.prototype.toString = function(){
  return '[Person]'
}

moe = new Person("Mo", "El")


func = moe.say.bind(moe)

console.log(func("asdasda"))
```

I don't know when there is a time I want to make a function equal to some other variable and use that variable instead of the original function, let alone that variable is equal the binding of an instance of the `Person` object.

Any good examples?

Comment: Well, you would use it whenever you pass a funcrion somewhere and you want `this` or a specific parameter have a certain value.

Comment: setTimeout(alert.bind(null, 123), 500);

Comment: var isBlank=Function.call.bind(/^\S*$/.test);

Comment: var toLower=Function.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a nutshell, `.bind()` returns a new function that when called will call the original function with a specific `this` value and (optionally) some new arguments preprended to the argument list.

`.bind()` is used when you need to pass a callback (e.g. some sort of function reference), but you want the caller to call your function with a specific `this` value.  This is most common when your function is actually a method and you want the `this` value set to be the a specific object so the method will operate on that specific object .  If you don't use `.bind()` in those cases, then the `this` value will be determined by the caller (not you) and if the caller doesn't set it specifically, it will end up being the global object or (in strict mode) `undefined`.  If what you were passing was a method that relies on a specific value of `this` in order to do its job, it would not work properly with the wrong `this` value.

So, if you want to control the value of `this` when your callback is called, you can use `.bind()`.  Internally, `.bind()` just creates a small stub function that just remembers the `this` value you pass it and calls your function with `.apply()` to set the `this` value.  `.bind()` is not magic as it can be done manually too.

`.bind()` also has the capability to add extra arguments to the function so, if you want to add arguments beyond what the normal caller of the callback uses, you can specify those with `.bind()` too.  It creates a stub function that will add these extra arguments and set the `this` value.

---

Let's say you have your `Person` object and you want to hook a button up to the `.say()` method for a particular `Person` object.

```
<button id="talk">Talk</button>
```

And, if you tried this javascript:

```
"use strict";
var bob = new Person("Bob", "Smith");
document.getElementById("talk").addEventListener("click", bob.say);
```

What you would find is that the `say()` method is called, but it would be missing two things.  It would be missing the right `this` reference (which would be set to the `button` object because that's how addEventListener calls its callbacks) and it would be missing the argument that `say(message)` expects.

So, you could solve this yourself with your own stub function that calls `bob.say()` with all the right arguments:

```
"use strict";
var bob = new Person("Bob", "Smith");
document.getElementById("talk").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    bob.say("Hello");
});
```

Or, you could use `.bind()`:

```
"use strict";
var bob = new Person("Bob", "Smith");
document.getElementById("talk").addEventListener("click", bob.say.bind(bob, "Hello"));
```

---

There is no magic in `.bind()`.  It can be entirely simulated in javascript.  In fact, here's a polyfill for it from MDN:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

This may look more complicated than it is because of all the error checking, but it's really just return a new function that combines two sets of arguments and then calls the original function with a specific `this` value.

Answer (score 6):

This is possibly the simplest way to explain it in a practical sense. Since most answers have given a theoretical definition and explanation, I will show a straightforward use case. You would use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) when you want to the function being called to have a different this value than the default one.

```
var NS = {
  user     : "self",
  getUser  : function() { return this.user; }
};

var CLOSURE = NS.getUser;

// error user is undefined, "this" in that context refers to the global object, "window"
console.log(CLOSURE());

// Bind the function call to NS object
console.log(CLOSURE.bind(NS)());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ev3z3td3/2/

Answer (score 3):

Use `bind()` when you want a function that always runs with a specific `this` value.

It's useful for more functional programming, when passing around functions as callbacks or event handlers.

```
var User = function(name) { this.name = name; };
User.prototype.poke = function() { alert "Hey, don't poke " + this.name; };
var bob = User('Bob');

// assume jQuery for brevity, and because it screws with `this` in callbacks
$('#some-element').click(bob.poke.bind(bob));
```

This will alert "Hey, don't poke Bob" because you passed it a bound function. So if that element, was explicitly about Bob, it makes sense to bind the event handler to him.

---

But there are other ways to do this without `bind`, of course.

```
$('#some-element').click(function() {
  bob.poke();
});
```

The difference can be a matter of style. And `bind` didn't use to have lots of support in all browsers, so lots of JS programmers figured out other ways to do it, and lots of those other ways are still in use today.

---

One *clear* win is when you want to pass the same function around to many different places, and you want an explicitly set `this`.

```
var bobPoke = bob.poke.bind(bob);

onFoo(bobPoke);
onBar(bobPoke);
onBaz(bobPoke);
```