# ECMA double fat arrow use?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

Can you explain this code? Is it currying?

```
    export const thing = (...items) => (wotsit) => {
        const thing = (props, {enums}) => {
            // ...
        };

        thing.contextTypes = {
            enums: PropTypes.object
        };

        return thing;
    };

    export default thing;
```

Comment: `=>` that lambda used for anonymous function, `export` are used to export function, variables which can be imported by other files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. Without the [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), it will look like this:

```
export const thing = function(...items) {

    // `items` will be an array with all the arguments that you pass in.

    return function(wotsit) {
        const thing = function(props, {enums}) {
            // ...
        };

        thing.contextTypes = {
            enums: PropTypes.object
        };

        return thing;
    };
};

export default thing;
```

On the other hand, this:

```
const thing = (props, {enums}) => {
    // ...
};
```

Is using parameters [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's the same as this:

```
const thing = (props, options) => {
    let enums = options.enums;
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use `bind` here, as you haven't used fat arrows in your code?

Comment: Just if you are using `this` inside any of those functions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477245/when-to-use-bind-in-js

Comment: I guess it's the implicit return that threw me -- so much ECMA has all the legibility of early 1990's Perl code. The Perl community made implicit returns (and much else) socially unacceptable, I hope the ECMA peeps follow suit soon.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning back a function to be called at a later time. If the functions were not in ES6, it would look something like:

```
function thing(a, b) {
    return function(wotsit) {
        const thing = {};
        ...
        return thing;
    }
}
```

Which would eventually work something like this:

```
let a = thing(1, 2);
let b = a(wotsit); // Gives you back thing object
```