# How do I know when to use .bind() on a function in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, this, bind

*(I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477245/when-to-use-bind-in-js) question, but the answers don't quite tell me what I need to know.)*

I've come across cases where I need to use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on a function in JavaScript in order to pass `this` or local/class variables to a function. However, I still don't really know when it's needed.

**What is the criteria for knowing when `this` or local/class variables will or will not be available in a function, exactly? How do you reason about this?**

For instance:

- When a new anonymous `function() { }` is created, wrapped, or passed around?
- When using a `class` member function, a `class` getter/setter function, or an oldschool `prototype.function` "member function" (of a function acting as a class)?
- In the global scope?
- In a `for` or `forEach` loop, or any of their variants?
- In a closure outer or inner function?
- In various JS operations like `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` or `[].forEach.call()`?
- In various JS libraries and scripts, which may have their own custom implementation of things?

The main reason I ask is to be aware of potential pitfalls and to avoid having to rely on trial and error.

Comment: At least related: [*How does the `this` keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Comment: you only need to use it if your function code use `this` and it's not working otherwise. minor exception apply, like using it for currying, but let's keep it simple.

Comment: Also at least related: [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @dandavis No, that's **exactly** what I **don't** want to do. Trial and error is not a good way to write code, especially as it scales. I want to understand what's going on.

Comment: main point: you don't often need it. Once you get past the basics, trial and error is the only way to learn. In TDD, errors are actually purposeful: you want it to not work before it works, to verify your assumptions. The short answer to all your listed questions is "no", and they suggest you actually more need to understand how `this` is determined at runtime (ex: nothing to do with scope). The short list of common "yes" situations would be on promises using methods and event handlers to reach triggering elements (not e.target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Credit to [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57714406/1599699) and [Zapparatus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57714515/1599699) for their answers, which provided helpful info. Also helpful were these 4 answers/articles: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/1599699) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/1599699) [3](https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/) [4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)*

*However, these were either not entirely complete and/or very long-winded. So I have decided to combine all of my findings into one answer, along with code examples.*

---

There are several considerations to factor in when determining whether `this` or local/class variables will be available in a function:

- The function's containing scope
- The immediate predecessor in the call chain
- Whether the function is called directly or indirectly

*Note: there is also strict mode (which yields `undefined`'s rather than `window` objects) and arrow functions (which do not change `this` from the containing scope).*

---

Here are the explicit rules:

- By default, `this` is the global object, which in browser world is `window`.
- Inside a function in the global scope, `this` will still be `window`, it does not change.
- Inside a member function within a `class` or function-class (`new function() { }`), inside a function-class's prototype (`funcClass.prototype.func = function() { }`), inside a function called by a neighboring member function with `this`, or inside a function mapped in an object (`{ key: function() { } }`) or stored in an array (`[ function() { } ]`), **if the function is called directly with the class/object/array as the immediate predecessor in the call chain** (`class.func()`, `this.func()`, `obj.func()`, or `arr[0]()`), `this` refers to the class/object/array instance.
- Inside any closure's inner function (any function within a function), inside a returned function, inside a function called with a plain variable reference as its immediate predecessor in the call chain (**regardless of where it actually lives!**), or inside a function called indirectly (i.e. passed to a function (e.g. `.forEach(function() { })`) or set to handle an event), `this` reverts back to `window` **or** to whatever the caller may have bound it to (e.g. events may bind it to the triggering object instance).

  - There is... however... one exception...: if inside a `class`'s member function (and only a `class`, not a function-class), if a function within that loses its `this` context (e.g. by being a closure's inner function), it becomes `undefined`, rather than `window`...

---

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxsw2cb8/3/) with a bunch of code examples:

```js
outputBox = document.getElementById("outputBox");

function print(printMe = "") {
 outputBox.innerHTML += printMe;
}

function printLine(printMe = "") {
 outputBox.innerHTML += printMe + "<br/>";
}

var someVar = "someVar";

function func(who) {
 printLine("Outer func (" + who + "): " + this);
  var self = this;
  (function() {
   printLine("Inner func (" + who + "): " + this);
    printLine("Inner func (" + who + ") self: " + self);
  })();
}
func("global");
printLine();
func.call(someVar, "someVar");

printLine();

function funcTwo(who) {
 printLine("Outer funcTwo (" + who + "): " + this);
  var self = this;
  return function funcThree() {
   printLine("Inner funcThree (" + who + "): " + this);
    printLine("Inner funcThree (" + who + ") self: " + self);
  };
}
funcTwo("global")();
printLine();
f = funcTwo("global f");
f();
printLine();
funcTwo.call(someVar, "someVar")();

printLine();

object = {
  func: function(who) {
    printLine("Object outer (" + who + "): " + this);
    var self = this;
    (function() {
      printLine("Object inner (" + who + "): " + this);
      printLine("Object inner (" + who + ") self: " + self);
    })();
  }
}
object.func("good");
printLine();
bad = object.func;
bad("bad");

printLine();

function funcClass(who) {
 printLine("funcClass (" + who + "): " + this);
}
funcClass.prototype.func = function() {
 printLine("funcClass.prototype.func: " + this);
  self = this;
  (function() {
    printLine("funcClass.func inner: " + this);
    printLine("funcClass.func inner self: " + self);
  })();
}
fc = funcClass("bad");
printLine();
fc = new funcClass("good");
fc.func("good");

printLine();

class classClass {
 constructor() {
   printLine("classClass constructor: " + this);
  }
  func() {
   printLine("classClass.func: " + this);
    self = this;
    (function() {
     printLine("classClass.func inner: " + this);
      printLine("classClass.func inner self: " + self);
    })();
  }
  funcTwo() {
   this.func();
  }
}
cc = new classClass();
cc.func();
printLine();
printLine("Calling funcTwo:");
cc.funcTwo();

printLine();

[0].forEach(function(e) {
 printLine("[0].forEach: " + this);
  printLine("[0].forEach someVar: " + someVar);
});
[0].forEach(function(e) {
 printLine("[0].forEach with [0]: " + this);
}, [0]);

printLine();

arr = [
 function(who) {
   printLine("Array (" + who + "): " + this);
  },
  1,
  10,
  100
];
arr[0]("good");
arrFunc = arr[0];
arrFunc("bad");

printLine();

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
 printLine("button: " + this);
}
button.click();
button.onclick = func;
button.click();

setTimeout(function() {
 printLine();
 printLine("setTimeout: " + this);
  printLine("setTimeout someVar: " + someVar);
}, 0);

setTimeout(fc.func, 0);
setTimeout(cc.func, 0);
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="button"/>
<br/><br/>
<div id="outputBox" />
```

---

Conclusion: So yeah that's pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

The Mozilla Developer Network has some great documentation on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) specifying the different cases:

1. [Global context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Global_context)
2. [Function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context)
3. [using `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method)
4. [with arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions)
5. [in object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)
6. [in an object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_constructor)
7. [in DOM event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler)

Check out the links to get an idea of how `this` works in the different contexts and therefore when `bind` should be used to force bind a different `this` context for functions.

Usually, `bind` is used to transfer 'ownership' of a function. Specifically, in my experience, it was used back before classes were created to force an object method to be tied to the object in question. It is also useful for when using arrow functions because arrow functions have different contexts.

Comment: I would have included the link to arrow functions with [different contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) but I am a new contributor and was limited to the number of links I had.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `bind` (or a similar approach) when:

- The function is a traditional (`function` keyword) function or method (in a `class` or object literal), and
- That function will be called either in a way that doesn't set `this` explicitly or that sets it to an incorrect value

The reason is that with a traditional function or method, the value of `this` is set by the caller, **not** a part of the function itself. (Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).)

For example, consider:

```
const obj = {
    method() {
        console.log(this === obj);
    }
};
```

Now, when we do `obj.method()`, we're using syntax (calling the result of a property accessor operation) to specify what `this` will be, so:

```
obj.method();
// => true
```

But suppose we do this:

```
const m = obj.method;
```

Now, just calling `m()` will set `this` to the default `this` (`undefined` in strict mode, the global object in loose mode):

```
m();
// => false
```

Another way we can explicitly set `this` for the call is via `call` (and its cousin `apply`):

```
m.call(obj);
// => true
```

Some functions that call callbacks let you specify what `this` to use. `forEach` does, as an argument just after the callback:

```
[1].forEach(m, obj);
//          ^  ^^^---- the value to use as `this` in callback
//           \-------- the callback to call
// => true
```

Here's a live example of those:

```js
const obj = {
    method() {
        console.log(this === obj);
    }
};

obj.method();
// => true, `this` was set to `obj` because you did the call on the
// result of a property accessor
const m = obj.method;

m();
// => false, `this` was the default `this` used when `this` isn't
// specified explicitly via syntax or `call`

m.call(obj);
// => true, `this` was explicitly set via `call`

[1].forEach(m, obj);
// => true, `this` was explicitly set via `forEach`'s `thisArg` argument
```

So any time you have a function (such as the callback of a `forEach`, or an event handler), you need `bind` or a similar mechanism to ensure that the correct `this` is used.

This isn't true for some other kinds of functions, just traditional (`function` keyword) functions and methods (such as `obj.method` above). An arrow function *closes over* `this` instead of using the one supplied by the caller, and a bound function (result of using `bind`) has `this` bound to it and so ignores any `this` supplied by the caller.